# Dynamically create global variables within mixin?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I would like to generate "color weights" based on base colours.

```
@include generateColors(#518ef3, 'color-brand-1');
```

And this would create the following variables:

```
$color-brand-1: #518ef3; //base
$color-brand-1-300: lighten(#518ef3, 20%);
$color-brand-1-400: lighten(#518ef3, 10%);
$color-brand-1-500: #518ef3;
$color-brand-1-600: darken(#518ef3, 10%);
$color-brand-1-700: darken(#518ef3, 20%);
```

And I could then use that colour spectrum within the application via the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good idea.
Do a map to keep your color variables organized and you are good to go.

It's not possible (yet) to interpolate function or mixin names.

```
@function generateColorsWeights($color){
  @return (
    100: lighten($color, 30%),
    200: lighten($color, 20%),
    300: lighten($color, 10%),
    400: lighten($color, 5%),
    500: $color,
    600: darken($color, 5%),
    700: darken($color, 10%),
    800: darken($color, 20%),
    900: darken($color, 30%)
  )
}


@each $k,$color in generateColorsWeights(#518ef3){
  %colorName-#{$k} {
    color: $color
  }
}

.color{
  @extend %colorName-200
  //or
  color: map-get(generateColorsWeights(#518ef3),200)
}
```